# Spring OAuth2 SSO behind load balancer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have very simple Spring Boot application with Social Single Sign On feature.

It looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
class Application {
  // beans
}
```

And it has required entries in `application.yml`:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      # clientId: ...
      # clientSecret: ...
      accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      scope: email
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

It works pretty well on my local machine and when just one instance is started.

The problem happens when there are multiple instances which are hidden behind a load balancer.

Even though a user authenticates in the first request, subsequent request made to load-balancer are blocked due to 401.

Requests are routed to different app instance in comparison to the very first one.

---

I am trying to figure out, how I can make it stateless using JWT or JDBC, so it works across multiple instances. Unfortunately I didn't found any working example in the web.

There are some of them with requiring starting Authorization Server. But that's not my case, cause I want to entirely forward authorization to 3rd party provider (e.g. Google).

**What should I do to make the authorization works across multiple instances in such scenario?**

Answer (score 2):

Spring stores just ID of a session inside a cookie, but data is somewhere on webserver (tomcat?) and its fetched by this id. When your request hits other tomcat instance it just cant connect id to data. What you can do is to take a look at spring session project which uses redis instead specific instance filesystem.

Other way - which I dont recommend but may be ok for your solution - is to use sticky sessions on LB. LB will take care to pass user request to the same server over and over again. Of course this is not safe solution as when webserver dies your user will lose session / logout from app.

Comment: Thanks, finally I have used spring session with redis for backend. Unfortunately I was using also Vaadin, which provided me another bunch of problems in such infrastructure, but finally I have overcome them with some dirty hacks. Thanks for tips!

Comment: It didn't help, I used the other solutions with Spring Session Redis - https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-redis.html

Comment: "What you can do is to take a look at spring session project which uses redis instead specific instance filesystem."